# How to have border-radius in QT5 while using border-left?

Tags: c++, qt5

I have the styleSheet of QPushbutton

```
QPushButton
{
background-image: url(:/image.png);
background-position:  left center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
color: rgb(255,255,255);
border-radius: 5px;
background-color: rgb(120,120,120);
border: none;
text-align: left;
}
```

Now I require a 10px image padding.

```
QPushButton
{
background-image: url(:/image.png);
background-position:  left center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
color: rgb(255,255,255);
border-radius: 5px;
background-color: rgb(120,120,120);
padding-left: 44px;
border: none;
text-align: left;
border-left: 12px solid  rgb(120,120,120);
}
```

Now my left side no longer has border-radius. So how do I have the border-radius and padding the image at the same time? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Look at this documentation, you can notice in the image how border is placed above the content.

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-customizing.html#the-box-model

One thing I observed in your code is you made `border: none;`, which might have ignored your borders.

Just using `padding-left` should help....

May be something like below (not tested)

```
background-image: url(:/image.png);
background-position:  left center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
color: rgb(255,255,255);
border-radius: 5px;
background-color: rgb(120,120,120);
padding-left: 10px;
```

Comment: padding-left works with text but not with images.

Comment: I see. May be you can raise a bug to Qt. They may fix it in next version or release a patch if they notice it as critical

Comment: I tried and Photoshop assisted in resolving the issue flawlessly